# Getting a desired output through a loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a code to implement the following algorithm. In summary, I want to calculate arrays `Pe` and `v` by taking values at the previous step.

The current and desired outputs are attached.

The algorithm is

```
Pe[1]=Pe[0]*v[0]*t(=1)
v[1]=Pe[1]*4

Pe[2]=Pe[1]*v[1]*t(=2)
v[2]=Pe[2]*4
```

The code is

```
import numpy as np

arPe=[]
arv=[]

for t in range(0,3):
    if t == 0:
        Pe=np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]]) 
        v=2
        arPe.append(Pe) 
        arv.append(v) 
        IPe=np.array(arPe)
        Iv=np.array(arv)
    else:     
        Pe=Pe*v*t
        v=Pe*4
        arPe.append(Pe) 
        arv.append(v) 
        IPe=np.array(arPe)
        Iv=np.array(arv)
print("IPe =",[IPe])
print("Iv =",[Iv])
print("IPe shape =",IPe.shape)
print("Iv shape =",Iv.shape)
```

The current output is

```
IPe = [array([[[   1,    2,    3],
        [   4,    5,    6],
        [   7,    8,    9]],

       [[   2,    4,    6],
        [   8,   10,   12],
        [  14,   16,   18]],

       [[  32,  128,  288],
        [ 512,  800, 1152],
        [1568, 2048, 2592]]])]

Iv = [array([2, array([[ 8, 16, 24],
                 [32, 40, 48],
                 [56, 64, 72]]), array([[  128,   512,  1152],
                                        [ 2048,  3200,  4608],
                                        [ 6272,  8192, 10368]])],
      dtype=object)]
```

The desired output is

```
IPe = [array([[[   1,    2,    3],
        [   4,    5,    6],
        [   7,    8,    9]],

       [[   2,    4,    6],
        [   8,   10,   12],
        [  14,   16,   18]],

       [[  16,   64,  144],
       [ 256,  400,  576],
       [ 784, 1024, 1296]]])]

Iv = [array([2, array([[ 8, 16, 24],
                 [32, 40, 48],
                 [56, 64, 72]]), array([[  64,  256,  576],
                                        [1024, 1600, 2304],
                                      [3136, 4096, 5184]])],
      dtype=object)]
```

Comment: Suspiciously similar to [Defining a specific loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669424/defining-a-specific-loop-in-python) but posted on a new account.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in every step - maybe you calculate for wrong values. OR maybe your expected result is not correct - did you calculate it on paper?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny you are right. And in current answer I get expected result in the same way as in previous answer :)

Comment: Question is duplicated with this one(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669424/defining-a-specific-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to code in question [Defining a specific loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669424/defining-a-specific-loop-in-python)
I can get expected result only if I use

```
    if t == 1:
        Pe = Pe*v*t
    else:
        Pe = Pe*v*(t-1)
```

So it may suggest that algorithm is different - or algorithm is correct but you expect wrong result.

---

Minimal working code

```
import numpy as np

arPe = []
arv = []

# --- t == 0 ---

Pe = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]) 
v = 2
arPe.append(Pe) 
arv.append(v) 

# --- t > 0 ---

for t in range(1, 3):
    if t == 1:
        Pe = Pe*v*t
    else:
        Pe = Pe*v*(t-1)

    v = Pe*4

    arPe.append(Pe) 
    arv.append(v) 

# --- after loop ---

IPe = np.array(arPe)
Iv = np.array(arv)
        
print("IPe =", [IPe])
print("Iv =", [Iv])
print("IPe shape =", IPe.shape)
print("Iv shape =", Iv.shape)
```